# How can I tweek Xstream to handle XML to Java objects that include attributes and values?

Tags: xml-serialization, xstream

For example, how would form an object from XML written like this?

```
<name length="4">Ryan</name>
```

I would normally alias a class using an annotation to "name" and then have a length and a field for the name. However, this will not work because the second field has no name.

*Edit confusing wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since I used xstream (2+ years) but I do remember using converters to change the way that objects are serialized.  Check out http://x-stream.github.io/converters.html.  Also this tutorial, http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html, has some examples with attributes down towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JAXB?

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlRootElement
public class Name {

    @XmlValue
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private int length;
}
```

Comment: Check out my blog post comparing JAXB & XStream:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html